# "Folder Tree" Permissions - Site documents

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, permissions, team-sites

I need your help with set a permissions to a folder tree i created on SharePoint Online.

I created a new site, inside i create documents library 
which looks like:

- **folder1**

  - subfolderA
  - subfolderB
- **folder2**

  - subfolderC
  - subfolderD
- **folder3**

  - subfolderE
  - subfolderF

I want to grant access to the site to all of my users but restrict them to view what they didn't need to view

For example:
Marketing users need to enter the site but to show only folder2 and subfolderC.

I tried to share the FolderC directly from Sharepoint online, the user tried to enter the team site but it required a view permission to the whole site and now he can see FolderA

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Click on the folder then click on `Share` button, there you will find `Share With` and then click on `ADVANCED` --> I'll be inside the `Folder Permission` page --> stop `Inherting Permissions`
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Technically this is entirely possible.

In a nutshell:

- You need to have a site-scope permissions which grants desired permissions for all of the users that should be accessible to the site
- For your document library, you need to set unique permissions for each parent-folder (folder1, folder2, folder3), and again unique permissions for each subfolder (subfolderA, ... , subfolderF) according to their user group

You should pay attention when planning the document library, that the user scope must always be equal or smaller on a lower level (sub-level) when compared to the parent level. This means, that the users should always have a logically navigable path to the folders they are meant to access. E.g. if a user has an access to subfolderD, the user must also have an access to folder2.

I'd advice to refer to the Microsoft's documentation about [setting subfolder permissions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-the-permissions-on-a-subfolder-5427BD7C-F20A-4F75-8CF2-5359DD45A1A6).

> 1. Navigate to the site and library for which you want to create unique
>      permissions on a subfolder.
> 2. If necessary, create the subfolder and add a few files.
> 3. On the subfolder name, do the following:
>
>    a. Next to the subfolder name, click the **Ellipsis…**
>
>    b. On the file popup window, click the **Ellipsis…**, and then click **Shared**
>      **With**.
>
>    c. To view the folder’s Permissions page, click **Advanced**.
> 4. To remove permission inheritance for the folder, click **Stop Inheriting**
>      **Permissions**.
> 5. For existing users, edit the permissions of those in the current list
>      by selecting the check boxes and clicking either **Edit User Permissions**
>      or **Remove User Permissions**.
> 6. For new users, click **Grant Permissions** and fill out the dialog box.
>      Make sure you click **Show options** and select the appropriate permission
>      level.

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to control user permissions to view content at the Document Library level than at the folder level.  Create different document libraries for the confidential content and have a specific permission group for that (or those) level(s) of access.